# How to close the form after 3 unsuccessful tries?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login form with a password only. I want this login form to be closed if user enters the password wrong 3 times.

I declare this variable in class body:

```
int loginAttempts = 0;
```

When the login is wrong I use:

```
loginAttempts++;
```

In the login button enter event I use:

```
private void login_bt_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (loginAttempts == 3)
     {
         login logf = new login();
         logf.Close();
     }
}
```

This does not seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: It is working. you closed the brand new form you made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing `logf` instance which you create and even don't show. I think you need to close current form:

```
login_bt_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (loginAttempts == 3)            
        Close(); // simply close current form            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are creating the newinstance of the login form and then closing.

**Solution :** you need to close the already existing/Opened login form.

so that you need to get the already opened login form usinf `Application.OpenForms[]`

Try This:

```
if (loginAttempts == 3)
{
  login form = (login) Application.OpenForms["login"];
  form.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an instance, just close the current form:

```
if (loginAttempts == 3)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting at 0 and checking at ==3 will allow 4 attempts